# What is the meaning of the Equation of Geodesic Deviation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differential-geometry, geodesics

I've seen the Equation of Geodesic Deviation stated in several text as:$$\frac{D\xi^2}{dt^2}+Riemann(\textbf U,\xi,\textbf U)=0$$ but I haven't seen a real good explanation of why it works or the meaning of the right hand side of the equation.  Why is it zero?  Some texts and [posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391368/geodesic-deviation-equation) seem to suggest that this is Newton's First Law at work or an assumption of Minkowski space (objects at rest stay at rest, objects in motion stay in motion, acceleration is zero).  Is the zero on the right hand side of the equation an expression of Newton's First Law of Motion?

**EDIT:** The Equation of Geodesic Deviation appears to be asking the question, what shape would allow these objects that appear to be accelerating (e.g. the Moon, the Earth, the Sun), to be in "free fall". The Riemann appears to be the answer to the 'what shape' part of the question, but the right hand side, zero in Newtonian Dynamics, appears to be the desired answer of the equation: a test particle in "free fall" with respect to a fudicial geodesic.

Answer (score 1):

The geodesic deviation equation describes the behaviour of a one-parameter family of neighboring geodesics $\gamma_s(t)$, that is for each $s$, $\gamma_s$ is a geodesic parameterized by the affine parameter $t$. Defining the tangent vector $T^\mu = \partial x^\mu / \partial t$ and the deviation vector $S^\mu = \partial x^\mu / \partial s$, we have

$A^\mu = D^2 S^\mu / dt^2 = R^\mu_{\nu \rho \sigma} T^\nu T^\rho S^\sigma$

where:
$A^\mu$ relative acceleration of geodesics
$D / dt = (dx^\mu / dt) \nabla _\mu$ directional covariant derivative

Coming to your first question: "Why the R.H.S. of the equation is zero?", as you can read it is not. The explanation why in many texts all the terms are in the L.H.S. is because they use the antisymmetry of the last two indices of the Riemann tensor. They swap the indices $\rho$ and $\sigma$ getting a minus sign which is then offset by moving the Riemann term to the L.H.S. The swap of the indices attaches to the deviation vector the third index of the Riemann tensor, thus posting the vector in the second slot out of the three available in Riemann.

As for the second question, you have to explicit the Riemann tensor in that geometry.

Comment: I disagree.  The original statement of the Equation of Geodesic Deviation appears to be, objects in "free fall" may appear to accelerate with respect to a fudicial geodesic, but since we know there are no forces on the object, then it must be the geometry of space that causes the acceleration.  If we remove the acceleration with a shape, we can satisfy our condition that objects at rest do not accelerate.  The Riemann appears to be the reverse engineering of that assumption.

Comment: That is, the Equation of Geodesic Deviation appears to be asking the question, what shape would allow these objects that appear to be accelerating (e.g. the Moon, the Earth, the Sun), to be in "free fall". The Riemann appears to be the answer to the 'what shape' part of the question, but your first equation above appears to be disregarding the context of the original question (that is, that the result of the equation is a test particles in a condition of "free fall").

Comment: I copied that last part into the original post as it seems to sum up the original question.

Comment: Yes, the tidal force experienced by a free-falling macroscopic object is due to the curvature of the geometry. You are confusing a test particle with a macroscopic object. A test particle in free fall does not experience any force as, by definition, its dimensions are negligible compared to the curvature. Instead a macroscopic object extension suffers of geodesics which are in relative acceleration. The meaning of the equation is exactly that.

Comment: So what does the $0$ on the R.H.S. represent?  An assumption of locally Lorentzian geometry, or the assumption of Newton's First Law at the macroscopic level?

Comment: In my answer you read that the R.H.S. is not zero. I think that is the meaningful way to write the equation. Of course every equation can be shown with all the terms moved on the L.H.S., just changing the sign, and so to have the R.H.S. nil. However the meaning of the geodesic deviation equation is that neighboring geodesics are in relative acceleration given by the curvature. Instead a generalization of the Newton's first law is given by the geodesic equation (not the deviation equation) where the R.H.S. is really zero (proper acceleration nil).

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

What you call the equation of geodesic deviation is called the Jacobi equation and the vector field $\xi$ is called the Jacobi field. The idea is the following.

**A.** Assume that you are given a space (smooth manifold) $M$ that has some Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian metric.

**B.** Let $\gamma(t)$ be one fixed geodesic of that metric.

**Definition.** A Jacobi field $\xi(t)$ along the fixed geodesic $\gamma(t)$ is a vector field defined as follows:

**1.** let us assume that $\gamma(t)$ is included in a smooth one-parameter family of geodesics $\gamma(t, \sigma)$ such that $\gamma(t, 0) = \gamma(t)$. Smooth one-parameter family of geodesics means that the map $$\gamma \, : \, (t_1, t_2) \times (- \,\epsilon,\, \epsilon) \, \to \, M $$ is a smooth map such that for any fixed $\sigma \in (- \,\epsilon,\, \epsilon)$ the curve $\gamma(t, \sigma)$ is a geodesic of the space $M$.

**2.** Then the Jacobi vector field $\xi$ along $\gamma$ for the family of geodesics is 
$$\xi(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \, \gamma(t, \sigma)\Big|_{\sigma=0}
\,\,\,\,\,\text{ (i.e. first differentiate with respect to $\sigma$ and then plug $\sigma = 0$ )}$$

In other words, Jacobi vector fields along some fixed geodesic $\gamma$ describe in what directions and how much one should push $\gamma$ to turn it into a near-by geodesic. The Jacobi vector fields are very special because if you take an arbitrary vector field along $\gamma$ and use it to push $\gamma$ in the direction of that arbitrary field, the result may not be another geodesic but an arbitrary curve.

So the converse question arises: How can I tell whether a vector field $\xi(t)$ defined along a geodesic $\gamma(t)$ is a Jacobi vector field -- i.e. if for each $t$ I push $\gamma(t)$ along $\xi(t)$ would the result be another geodesic? Well, the answer is the Jacobi differential equation. In other words,

**Theorem.** A vector field $\xi(t)$ along the geodesic $\gamma(t)$ satisfies the Jacobi equation $$\frac{D^2}{dt^2}\xi + R\left(\xi, \frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right)\,\frac{d\gamma}{dt} = 0 $$ if and only if there is a smooth one parameter family of geodesics $\gamma(t, \sigma)$ sich that $\gamma(t, 0) = \gamma(t)$ and    $$\xi(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \, \gamma(t, \sigma)\Big|_{\sigma=0} $$

To justify this theorem you have to prove it in both directions, but I can sketch the direction which states that if $\xi(t)$ is a Jacobi field, then it must satisfy the Jacobi equation, i.e. deriving the Jacobi equation.

The Jacobi equation is simply the first variation of the geodesic equation. That is why the right hand side is equal to zero. Because the right hand side of the geodesic equation is zero. Here is what I mean: for each $\sigma$ the curve $\gamma(t, \sigma)$ is a geodesic. Then the geodesic equation says 
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)} \,\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) = 0 $$ Now, if you differentiate this geodesic equation with respect to $\sigma$ and set $\sigma = 0$ you get the Jacobi equation 
$$\frac{D^2}{dt^2}\xi + R\left(\xi, \frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right)\,\frac{d\gamma}{dt} = 0 $$

Indeed, differentiating with respect to $\sigma$ means taking the covariant derivative with respect to $\sigma$, i.e.
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma)} \left( \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)} \,\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) \right) = 0$$ 
However, by the definition of the Riemann tensor
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma)}  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)} = 
\nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)}  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma)} + R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma), \, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) \right)$$ so
\begin{align}
0 =& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma)}  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)} \,\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) = \\
=& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)}  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma)}\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) + R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma), \, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) \right) \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) = \\
=& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}\left(  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}}\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}\right) + R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}, \, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t} \right) \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}
\end{align}
However, if by we come back to the interpretation of $\gamma$ as a two-parameter smooth map, as given in point **1** above, then 
$$\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) = \gamma_{*(t,\sigma)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \,\,\, \text{ and }\,\,\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma) = \gamma_{*(t,\sigma)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}$$ where $\gamma_{*(t,\sigma)}$ is the derivative map (the tangent map) of the map $\gamma$ at the point $(t,\sigma)$. Based on the fact that there is no torsion of the covariant derivative, since it comes from a metric
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}}\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t} =& 
\nabla_{\gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}}\, \gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} = \nabla_{\gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\, \gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} + \left[\gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}\right] =  \\ =& 
\nabla_{\gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\, \gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} +  \gamma_{*}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}\right] = 
 \nabla_{\gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\, \gamma_{*} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} + 0 \\ =& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}
\end{align}

So we continue the derivation of the Jacobi equation
\begin{align}
0 =& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma)}  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)} \,\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) = \\
=& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)}  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma)}\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) + R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma), \, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) \right) \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) = \\
=& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}\left(  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}}\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}\right) + R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}, \, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t} \right) \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t} = \\
=& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}\left(  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}\right) + R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}, \, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t} \right) \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t} = \\
=& \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)}\left(  \nabla_{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)}\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma)\right) + R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, \sigma), \, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma) \right) \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, \sigma)
\end{align} Now, set $\sigma = 0$ in which case 
$$\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}(t, 0) = \frac{d\gamma}{dt}(t) \,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \sigma}(t, 0) = \xi(t)$$ Consequently, the equation above turns into
\begin{align}
0 =& \nabla_{\frac{d \gamma}{d t}(t)}\left(  \nabla_{\frac{d \gamma}{d t}(t)}\, \xi(t)\right) + R\left( \xi(t), \,\frac{d \gamma}{d t}(t) \right) \frac{d \gamma}{d t}(t)
\end{align}
Recall that $$\nabla_{\frac{d \gamma}{d t}(t)} \nabla_{\frac{d \gamma}{d t}(t)} = \frac{D^2}{dt^2}$$ as a notation and we arrive at the Jacobi equation
$$\, \frac{D^2 \xi}{dt^2}  + R\left( \xi, \,\frac{d \gamma}{d t}(t) \right) \frac{d \gamma}{d t}(t) = 0$$

I assume your last question about the sphere with changing radius is asked out of confusion. The topic of Jacobi equations and Jacobi fields does not require for the metric and the whole geometry to be changing. The geometry usually stays fixed. If the geometry changes with respect to some parameters, simply all the quantities involved in the Jacobi equation will additionally depend on these parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your derivation of the Jacobi equation, but my question is not asked out of confusion.  The most pervasive, untested assumption in General Relativity is that the everywhere geometry of spacetime is locally Lorentzian.  I claim that objects at rest accelerate.  Your derivation above appears to me to assume that the manifold, M, is constant with time.  That appears to be what the zero on the right hand side of the equation is doing for you.  I claim that constant M is a mathematical abstraction with no analog in the real universe.

Comment: The manifold is always constant because it is a differential topological object. Even in your example you always have the sphere as topological manifold. The only thing that changes is the geometric structure (the metric of the sphere changes), which can be described by a changing radius. Any mathematical theory you write, I will make your underlying manifold constant.

Comment: I have no doubt you can incorporate it into the Rienmann, but is the better abstraction to place the constant acceleration on the right hand side where you currently assume zero.

Comment: The right hand side of Jacobi equation is zero because it is the derivative of the geodesic equation, whose right hand side is also zero. If you want something to appear on the right, the geodesic equation will not be geodesic anymore.

Comment: The Jacobi equation is describing the second derivative of the length of a vector with respect to proper time.  The units are acceleration.  The Rienmann part of the equation appears to be describing a curvature such that when it's added to the acceleration, the resulting test particle will appear to be in 'free fall', which is the standard definition of a geodesic.  My point is, if 'free fall' were  redefined to include an intrinsic acceleration (i.e. objects at rest accelerate), then the curvature would need to adjust so that the result was this constant acceleration.

Comment: In general relativity, the space time is globally Lorentzian. I do not know what you mean by this fact being untested assumption. It is a mathematical model whose predictions and derivations match very well real life observations and phenomena. If you have an alternative theory, write it down and maybe someone will check it and referee it.

Comment: OK. (1) You have obviously never tried to use General Relativity on something larger than a solar system.  It fails all these tests miserably.  The only way this failed theory can be made to match observation is to add in a kind of matter that has no analog in the real universe and has no theoretical foundation that has passed a single experimental test. (2) I'm writing the paper as we speak, but having a difficult time finding scientists.  Plenty of clerics who preach dogma, but very few scientists who are capable of questioning the basic assumptions that have led them astray.

Comment: The Jacobi equation describes the variation of a geodesic within a family of geodesics. I do not think it describes the free fall of test particles. I think the geodesic equation describes the free fall of test particles.

Comment: The Equation of Geodesic Deviation was the subject of my original post, not the Jacobi, though I did appreciate the background.

Comment: Equation of Geodesic Deviation  = Jacobi field equation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation

Comment: I don't know if this was a mis-type or a misunderstanding *"In general relativity, the space time is globally Lorentzian"*  General Relativity is only locally Lorentzian.